# ExpectedExceptionBaseAttribute in VS2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I ran into an issue this morning after upgrading to Visual Studio 2012.

Specifically, I have a class that extends ExpectedExceptionBaseAttribute. The test passes in Visual Studio 2010 but fails in 2012.

The issue on Microsoft Connect is [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758875/-testtools-unittesting-class-derived-from-expectedexceptionbaseattribute-fails) which has been closed as "by design" but in my opinion, this is a bug. Whilst there is a resolution provided by Microsoft, it requires me to force the new version of MSTest into a legacy mode.

I have not included sample code here because there is a small sample project available for download on the Connect issue.

If, as they state in the comments, the new version of MSTest is leaner and more performant, then I want to use it without putting it into a legacy mode.

So the question is how do get it to work without resorting to that?

Comment: Any news? Really annoying "improvement"(

Comment: No news I'm afraid. I refactored my code in the end with multiple asserts but it's nowhere near as clean as using the attribute. I was only using it in a couple of places so not such a big deal for me. Still irked by it though!

Comment: It is now July 2013... the bug still appears to exist :(

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in VS2012 Update 3.